# Setting Active a 3rd person character controller through script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have applied a `3rd person character controller` to an avatar, and everything seems fine.

Once I disable the avatar game object, and use the following code to re-activate it at run time:

```
public GameObject avatar;

void Start()
    {
        avatar.SetActive(true);
    }
```

I get the following error message:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson.ThirdPersonCharacter.CheckGroundStatus () (at Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/ThirdPersonCharacter/Scripts/ThirdPersonCharacter.cs:217)
UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson.ThirdPersonCharacter.Move (Vector3 move, Boolean crouch, Boolean jump) (at Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/ThirdPersonCharacter/Scripts/ThirdPersonCharacter.cs:56)
UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson.ThirdPersonUserControl.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/ThirdPersonCharacter/Scripts/ThirdPersonUserControl.cs:73)
```

When I click on it, the main error instance seems to be in the following block of code, in the line with `apply root motion`:

```
void CheckGroundStatus()
{
    RaycastHit hitInfo;

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    // Helper to visualise the ground check ray in the scene view.
    Debug.DrawLine( transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f) + (Vector3.down * m_GroundCheckDistance) );
    #endif
    // 0.1f is a small offset to start the ray from inside the character.
    // It is also good to note that the transform position in the sample assets is at the base of the character.
    if ( Physics.Raycast( transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), Vector3.down, out hitInfo, m_GroundCheckDistance ) )
    {
        m_GroundNormal = hitInfo.normal;
        m_IsGrounded = true;
        m_Animator.applyRootMotion = true;
    }
    else
    {
        m_IsGrounded = false;
        m_GroundNormal = Vector3.up;
        m_Animator.applyRootMotion = false;
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me understand why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have assigned Animator from Unity Editor but from code (function **Start**) but this code didn't run because it wasn't enabled at beginning of scene.

Other problem might be that you removed Animator from Game Object where you have your **ThirdPersonCharacter** script.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use `GetComponent`:

```
GetComponent<Animator>().applyRootMotion = true;
```

Don't use a variable.